# Access other className on hover in emotion css

Tags: css, styled-components, emotion

I use [EmotionCSS](http://emotion.sh). I want to get an access to other className while catching focus on another. For example I have a component like that:

```
<div className={styles.root}>
  <input className={styles.input} ... />
<div/>
```

The style file looks like that:

```
import { css } from '@emotion/css';

export const styles = {
  root: css`
    border: 1px solid black;
  `

  input: css`
    ... 

    &:focus {
      // Here I want to access 'root' className and change its colour. Is it possible?
    }

  `,
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use the `:has()` pseudo-class on the **root** to change the focus styles in **input** tag.

```js
import { css } from "@emotion/css";

export const styles = {
  root: css`
    border: 3px solid black;
    &:has(input:focus) {
      border-color: red;
    }
  `,
  input: css`
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    &:focus {
      text-transform: uppercase;
    }
  `
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className={styles.root}>
        <input type="text" className={styles.input} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit dazziling-code]